# Should I UV map a joined mesh or keep the meshes separate when exporting a character to a game engine?

Tags: uv

I want to create a character with a weapon and then export it to a game engine.

Should I join all the meshes (character and weapon) and start UV mapping so I have 1 mesh and 1 texture or do I need to UV map separate meshes?

What's the difference between the two ways?

I want to create a character that only has 1 unique weapon, like in League of Legends.

Comment: Hi. I hope you don't mind my edit. If you do please use the edit link and re-edit the question. I hope I did not change the any of the meaning you intended and it is clearer, without any unnecessary text that does not contribute to communicating your question now and this will help you get better answers sooner.

Comment: It's alright to edit my post, because i am still bad at English.

Answer (score 1):

As the weapon its other independent object I would not join it with the character, and you can use as many texture as you want if you have different materials.